# Does it harm if we remove system bloatware in rooted device?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I've rooted my Android 5.0 device and later I removed the system pre-installed apps, does this cause any harm to my device... Please help me out.

Comment: Please provide app name which you want to remove because it will depend on the app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what pre-installed apps you have removed. Some could be safely removed with no harm, some might interfere in smooth functioning of your phone, while others would cause serious problem. Here is [a list of system apps of a Samsung device](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1487073), and the author made a detailed analysis on which are safe to remove and which are not. Hope it works as a reference for your device.